# RDC not working from outside

Tags: remote-desktop

I've set up Remote Connection according to : http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network

That is,

1. Allow remote connections to the computer you want to access.
2. Make sure Remote Desktop is able to communicate through your firewall.
3. Find the IP address of the computer on your home network that you want to connect to.
4. Open your router's configuration screen and forward TCP port 3389 to the destination computer's IP address.
5. Find your router's public IP address so that Remote Desktop can find it on the Internet.

When I'm inside the LAN, RDC works flawlessly. When I try to connect to the ip given by my ISP it cannot connect.

I've setup port forwarding for 3389 on my netgear router.

Thanks!

Comment: What error message do you get? What is the result when you try `telnet YOUR_EXTERNAL_IP 3389`?

Comment: Is this a corporate environment where IPSEC is configured? Because that'll do it. Otherwise, I'd double check that #4 is really done, and that #3 hasn't changed suddenly, and that your ISP isn't blocking TCP:3389 on their end or something.